# check if any of the items of a list is in a line of a file, if not, then send mail

Tags: python, list

I have a list, I need to check whether all the elements of this list are in the .cfg file, if one of these elements is not found in the file, it is necessary to write the missing element in the file_diff.html file and run the sender() function. If all items from the list have been found, run the main() function. I implemented it like this, but only the first element(v[0]) is checked. But elif is also processed as if nothing from the list is in the file.

```
    def validator():
                   v = ['ip arp inspection',
                       f'ip arp inspection vlan {l[2]}',
                       'ip dhcp snooping',
                       f'ip dhcp snooping vlan {l[2]}',
                       'ip dhcp snooping information option'
                       ]   
                   with open(f'/home/tftp/cfg/{today}/all/edgecore/{l[0]}.cfg', 'r') as val:
                       for line in val:
                           if all(word in line for word in v): 
                              main()
                       elif not any(word in line for word in v): 
                           with open('file_diff.html', 'w') as noname:
                              title = f"The configuration on switch {l[0]} do not valid"
                              noname.write(title)
                              sender()
```

Comment: Can you be a little more specific with the actual problem?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The problem is that I cannot check the elements from the letter in the file in one iteration. It searches for each element in turn and performs the sender or main function 5 times, as many as there are elements in the letter.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to check whether all the elements of this list are in the .cfg file
>
> ```
> for line in val:
>   if all(word in line for word in v): ...
> ```

You're checking if the **line** of the file having your strings **not the whole file.**
For this question I recommend using val.read():

```
if all(word in val.read() for word in v): ...
```

If problem not in this, add error code and problem part of it.

Comment: There is no error when executing the function. But empty reports from all my files that I checked came to the mail. That is, it was processed incorrectly, if it finds the terms I need in the file, then the report is not sent, if it does not find at least one of them, the report must be sent